# What is the equivalent of AWS Classic Load Balancer in GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

We have created an Instance Template with ubuntu operating system. Using the instance template, we have created instance group with 3 machines.
These 3 machines are behind a TCP Loadbalancer with 8080 port enabled.

We have run the below python command on first VM.
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

We see one of the instance health (1/3) is successful and have tested with telnet command. Since, the `SimpleHTTPServer` is installed on one instance, it shows (1/3) instance is healthy.

```
telnet <Loadbalacer ip> 8000
```

However, when we run the above command from the 2nd VM in the same instance group, we see 'Connection refused'.

```
telnet XX.XX.XX.XX 8000
Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused.
```

Also, the same service is accessible on other VMs running on other instance group. The service is not accessible within the same instance group.

We have verified the firewall rules and we have tested with both 'allow all' and 'Specified protocols and ports' Protocols and ports option.

The above usecase works fine on AWS Classic LoadBalancer, however this fails on GCP.

I have created a firewall rule, 'cluster-firewall-rule' with 'master-cluster-ports' as tag. This tag has been added as part of Network tags in the instance. This rule allows traffic for 8080 port.

What is the equivalent of AWS Classic Load Balancer in GCP?

Comment: GCP does not have the equivalent of AWS CLB. For your telnet problem, are you running the command behind the load balancer? Are you specifying public or private IP addresses? Have you created firewall rules for port 8000? Why is your healthchecks failing? Edit your question with details covering your VPC, firewall, load balancer and instance setup.

Comment: yes, I am running the command behind loadbalancer. Yes, my firewall rules allows 8080 port. Since 8080 port is running on only once instance, it shows one of three instances are healthy.

Comment: Edit your question with the details that I asked for.

Comment: You have a lot of questions that you have asked that are still open. You don't award answers or points.

Answer (score 0):

GCP does not have equivalent for AWS Classic Load Balancer (CLB).

AWS CLB was the first load balancer service from AWS and was built with EC2-Classic, with subsequent support for VPC. AWS NLB and ALB services are the modern LBs. If you can, I suggest using one of them. See https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/#compare for comparison between them.

If you switch, then you could use GCP's corresponding load balancer services. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/networking.

For my benefit:
1) Are you migrating applications from AWS to GCP?
2) What is your use case for migrating applications from AWS to GCP?

Comment: I am trying to install kubernetes on GCP. We are setting up kubernetes HA. I am able to bootstrap one master by running `kubeadm init --config=<filename>`. However, joining the 2nd master fails with below error.

error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap: failed to get config map: Get https://XX.XX.XX.XX:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config: dial tcp XX.XX.XX.XX:6443: connect: connection refused

Comment: @Sunil Gajula - I'm assuming you are using Kubernetes on GCP by hand installing on compute engines for practice?  Otherwise, I think I would strongly recommend Google's managed Kubernetes called GKE which creates a complete cluster for you in minutes.

Comment: @Kolban, We have tried with GKE, we wanted to try to install k8s on GCP.